# Flex: BusyIndicator on top of a button?

Tags: apache-flex, button, depth, busyindicator

I am a newbie to flex, using flex 4.6 with FB 4.7. I am trying to create a BusyIndicator "in front of" (and in the middle of) a Button. I found some examples on Google on image stacking, but for some reason it does not work with a button/indicator combination and I don't know why... I tried using the depth property, but it has no effect, the button appears above the indicator, i.e assuming the indicator is marked by [x]:

```
[button]
  [x]   <== indicator
```

What I want is that the indicator will be in front of, and in the middle of, the button:

```
[bu[x]ton]
```

Here is the layout I am using:

```
<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="top" horizontalAlign="center">       
    <s:Button id="mybtn" label="My Inbox" click="onInbox()" depth="1"/>
    <s:BusyIndicator id="myBusyIndicator" rotationInterval="50" depth="2" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Any ideas how to do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are misunderstanding what layout groups (`VGroup`, `HGroup`, `TileGroup`) do. They work in 2 dimensions, not three. So by placing two objects in a VGroup, they are stacked vertically along the y-axis, rather than along the z-axis (as you want).

What you want is to just use a simple `Group` here. Group has no `Layout` to it (it's the parent for Vgroup, and many other classes for that matter) and so all the positioning is handled by the children, rather than the parent (the Group).

```
<s:Group>
    <s:Button/>
    <s:BusyIndicator horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"/>
</s:Group>
```

That creates a button at level 0, and then places a BusyIndicator at level 1 (1 > 0), and centers it both horizontally and vertically (`horizontalCenter` and `verticalCenter` are in pixels from center to their respective axis)

Comment: Technically, the `Group` class *does* have a layout. It's the `BasicLayout` class, and it's what makes things like `horizontalCenter`, `verticalCenter`, and the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` constraints, and simple absolute positioning (with x/y coorindates) work.

Comment: @SunilD. Good call. Maybe I should have been more specific with the answer. Group behaves like an uber-Sprite, whereas VGroup and HGroup do not and actually have 1-axis control (at least by default) over their children. Either way, still good to know the difference.